# Apparent problem with Onedrive's ability to handle Dynamic URL Paths to files in OneDrive Folder for use as links in Power Apps data table

Tags: powershell, onedrive, powerapps, power-automate

I am attempting to build an App in Power Apps that gets security camera video based on a set of criteria, displays the list of videos in a gallery, and allows the user to select among them and play them in a media player window. The videos get updated from a button tied to a Power Automate flow.

I have have written the flow in Power Automate that runs a Powershell script that sorts thru a few thousand video files and identifies those that meet a set of criteria - the script produces a csv file containing a list of the identified video files, and copies the identified files up to a subdirectory on OneDrive. Another script then creates a different csv file - that  script appends the URL for the OneDrive folder to each file name inside the csv file - creating a one column csv file of URLs - each URL is supposed to point the individual video files in the OneDrive Folder. The whole process is dynamic and automated - so that when the files are updated - the csv files are updated as well.

Here is my problem -

When I append the file names to the end of the OneDrive folder URL, the combined URLs do not point to the individual files - each still only opens the folder containing all the files.

I've followed Microsoft Instructions posted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-images-pictures-audio-video

But to no avail.

The Instructions to "To copy the file path from OneDrive for Business, select a file, and then select Path (Copy direct link) from the details pane on the right side of the screen."........ simply Don't work.

So - here is my question - Does anyone know how to create URLs that points directly to individual files in a OneDrive folder - where the URL uses a fixed component for the OneDrive Folder URL, with appended filenames (files names being each of the files in the folder)?

The format would be something like this (one column csv with no header - and variable length):

[https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ\6_2021-05-12_05-08-26.mp4](https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ%5C6_2021-05-12_05-08-26.mp4)

[https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ\6_2021-05-12_05-08-35.mp4](https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ%5C6_2021-05-12_05-08-35.mp4)

[https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ\6_2021-05-12_05-09-45.mp4](https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ%5C6_2021-05-12_05-09-45.mp4)

[https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ\6_2021-05-13_05-08-26.mp4](https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ%5C6_2021-05-13_05-08-26.mp4)

[https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ\6_2021-05-13_07-09-05.mp4](https://bizopsanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gpowell_bizops_onmicrosoft_com/Ei4xRjBg?e=Jkq1fZ%5C6_2021-05-13_07-09-05.mp4)

.

.

.

If anyone has any ideas - I'd be so very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Gregg Powell Sierra Vista, AZ .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232412/discussion-on-question-by-gregg-powell-apparent-problem-with-onedrives-ability).

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out.....

One "simply" has to rearrange the structure of the OneDrive URL

For instance......

Here is how a URL must be structured for it to point to a file inside a onedrive folder.....

https://yourmicrosoftaccountname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/1stURLsegment/2ndURLsegment_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/1st_level_OneDrive_folder/2nd_level_OneDrive_folder/3rd_level_OneDrive_folder/filename.ext

Won't bother about going into any detail able how to structure the gallery in PowerApps such that it can use a dynamic list of files in a table to point to media files.